# Detect a "Hole" or "output" in a delimited zone with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to detect when a zone has some "holes" and where they are located from a source image. Source images can be random and have more than 1 hole.

[image]

I would like to find the red circle zones with my code but I don't where to start from.

I don't see any function to help me with that. drawContours won't be helpful there I think (already has been usefull to get those "zones")

Does someone see a way to do that in Python ? (perhaps not using openCV, i'm open to any free library)

Thanks !

Comment: (1) locate "endpoints". (2) for an endpoint, calculate nearest other end point, and consider if that's near enough or not. -- (1) is the trickier part. one approach is skeletonization and then traversing the skeleton and establishing the graph it represents.

Answer (score 2):

One possible method involves extracting the **biggest contour** (this is the largest "path" in your image), the filtering criteria could also involve directly getting the outermost contour. Then, check for the discontinuous points, in other words, the *endpoints* of the path. You are essentially asking for a lot of code. Luckily, I've developed a similar algorithm. There are two steps:

1. Find the biggest contour/blob/path
2. Find the path’s endpoints.

Let's see the code:

```
# Imports
import cv2
import numpy as np

fileName = "shape01.png"
path = "D://opencvImages//"

# Reading an image in default mode:
inputImage = cv2.imread(path + fileName)
# Prepare a deep copy of the input for results:
inputImageCopy = inputImage.copy()

# Grayscale conversion:
grayscaleImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold via Otsu:
_, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(grayscaleImage, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Find the biggest blob:
binaryImage = findBiggestBlob(binaryImage)
```

The first steps involves computing a binary image of the input. Then, extract the biggest contour from there. I have implemented a function called `findBiggestBlob`, which just computes the biggest blob on the image using its area. It returns an image of the biggest blob isolated; this comes from a [C++ implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60863162/how-to-remove-small-objects-from-image-after-segmentation/60896323#60896323) I wrote of the same idea.

This is the binary image:

[image]

This is the biggest contour:

[image]

Now, what follows is getting the [skeleton](https://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/05/skeletonization-using-opencv-python.html) of the binary image. The skeleton is a version of the binary image where lines have been normalized to have a width of `1 pixel`. This is useful because we can then convolve the image with a `3 x 3` kernel and look for specific pixel patterns - those that identify an end-point. Let's compute the skeleton using OpenCV's extended image processing module:

```
# Compute the skeleton:
skeleton = cv2.ximgproc.thinning(binaryImage, None, 1)
```

This is the skeleton:

[image]

The contour has now `1 px` of width, so we can detect the endpoints. The main idea of this approach is that the convolution yields a very specific value where patterns of black and white pixels are found in the input image. The value we are looking for is `110`, but we need to perform some operations before the actual convolution. Refer to the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586123/filling-gaps-in-shape-edges/) for details. These are the operations:

```
# Threshold the image so that white pixels get a value of 0 and
# black pixels a value of 10:
_, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(skeleton, 128, 10, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Set the end-points kernel:
h = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
              [1, 10, 1],
              [1, 1, 1]])

# Convolve the image with the kernel:
imgFiltered = cv2.filter2D(binaryImage, -1, h)

# Extract only the end-points pixels, those with
# an intensity value of 110:
endPointsMask = np.where(imgFiltered == 110, 255, 0)

# The above operation converted the image to 32-bit float,
# convert back to 8-bit uint
endPointsMask = endPointsMask.astype(np.uint8)
```

If we `imshow` the `endPointsMask`, we would get something like this:

[image]

In the above image, you can faintly see the location of the identified end-points. Let's get the coordinates of these white pixels:

```
# Get the coordinates of the end-points:
(Y, X) = np.where(endPointsMask == 255)
```

Finally, loop through these points and draw some circles located at the endpoints:

```
# Draw the end-points:
for i in range(len(X)):
    # Get coordinates:
    x = X[i]
    y = Y[i]
    # Set circle color:
    color = (0, 0, 255)
    # Draw Circle
    cv2.circle(inputImageCopy, (x, y), 3, color, -1)

    cv2.imshow("Points", inputImageCopy)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

For shape one, this is the final result:

[image]

This is the `findBiggestBlob` function:

```
def findBiggestBlob(inputImage):
    # Store a copy of the input image:
    biggestBlob = inputImage.copy()
    # Set initial values for the
    # largest contour:
    largestArea = 0
    largestContourIndex = 0

    # Find the contours on the binary image:
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(inputImage, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Get the largest contour in the contours list:
    for i, cc in enumerate(contours):
        # Find the area of the contour:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cc)
        # Store the index of the largest contour:
        if area > largestArea:
            largestArea = area
            largestContourIndex = i

    # Once we get the biggest blob, paint it black:
    tempMat = inputImage.copy()
    cv2.drawContours(tempMat, contours, largestContourIndex, (0, 0, 0), -1, 8, hierarchy)
    # Erase smaller blobs:
    biggestBlob = biggestBlob - tempMat

    return biggestBlob
```

Comment: This is very nice work!

Comment: Wow, such an amazing answer ! Thanks a lot for this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for your first answer so great !
So, i managed to do it on simple forms like posted above.
Now I'm starting the second step : Real Life.

What I want to do is from that :
[image]

Isolate the minimap and find the output.
Some filtering with :

```
def highlightWalls(image):
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

hsv_color3 = np.asarray([18, 98, 80])   
hsv_color4 = np.asarray([28, 125, 137])   
hsv_color5 = np.asarray([9, 0, 57])   
hsv_color6 = np.asarray([71, 29, 134])   
kernel = np.ones((3, 3))

mask1 = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, hsv_color3,hsv_color4)
mask2 = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, hsv_color5,hsv_color6)
mask = cv2.bitwise_xor(mask1, mask2)
blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(image,9,75,75)
image1= cv2.bitwise_and(blur,blur,mask=mask)
cv2.imshow("iamge1", image1)

finalMinimap = cv2.Canny(image1, 150, 200, None, 3)
img_dilate = cv2.dilate(finalMinimap, kernel, iterations=3)
cv2.imshow("walls", img_dilate)

return img_dilate
```

gives :
[image]

And Skeleton gives now :

[image]

Great job by now ! But I'm missing a last step : Remove all those little "branches" of the skeleton. If not :
[image]

Any idea from a boss there ?
P.S. : If you have some ideas to better filter my first image let me know of course !